# Show that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}s_n$ exists.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $s_1 = 1$ and $s_{n+1}=\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)s_n^2, \ for\ n \geq 1$.
Show that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} s_n$ exists.
How do I prove this??
And is it possible to show that the limit exists by showing that it is Cauchy sequence??

Comment: My first thought is to try and show that this is monotone.

Comment: Hint: $(s_n)$ is decreasing.

Answer (score 1):

Try to compute the first few terms. This should give you an idea.

**Hint:** show by induction that $\forall n \geq 1$, you have $0\leq s_n \leq 1$. Then show that the sequence $(s_n)_{n \geq 1}$ is decreasing.